# Access and VB6 Query for getting a value based on a range of numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

Am writing a query to get commission from a table `tblcommssion` but this depends on the amount entered in a text box.

E.g

```
| min_tier | max_tier | commission |
|----------| ---------| ---------- |
|   500    | 2500     | 100        | 
|   2501   | 5000     | 125        | 
|   5001   | 15000    | 450        |
```

my query is

```
Select commission
from tblAgentCommission
where min_tier <= '" & Format(txtWithAmount.Text, "##0")"' and
      max_tier >= '" & Format(txtWithAmount.Text, "##0") & "'
```

But it fetches wrong the commission, i.e one that does not correspond with the row e.g when I enter 4200, I expect commission to be 125 since 4200 lies between 2501 and 5000.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing strings and numbers.  This is dangerous, because the values are compared as *strings*.  Start by removing the quotes around the values:

```
Select commission
from tblAgentCommission
where min_tier <= " & Format(txtWithAmount.Text, "##0")" and
      max_tier >= " & Format(txtWithAmount.Text, "##0");
```

This assumes that `min_tier` and `max_tier` are numbers.  If they are strings, you also need to fix their types in the table.